# How to get values from DataView?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, dataview

When a user clicks an element in TreeView this function is triggered:

```
  private void treeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        Vozlisce v = (Vozlisce)treeView.SelectedItem;      
        v.tabela.pretvoriListVDataTable(); 
        seznam.ItemsSource = v.tabela.dt.DefaultView; 
    }
```

It copies elements from dt which is type `ObservableCollection<Vozlisce>`to a custom datagrid that has xaml:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="seznam" Margin="516,64,131.2,35.4" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}"  AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"  AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="name" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding ime}"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="value" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding utez}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

seznam.ItemsSource = v.tabela.dt.DefaultView;

My problem is when i try to get data from `DataGrid` when the user clicks a save button, it doesn't get the current changed data from datagrid, it copies the same data I put in at the beginning with `seznam.ItemsSource = v.tabela.dt.DefaultView;`

The save button function:

```
     private void btnShraniUtezi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {         
        DataView dataView = (DataView)seznam.ItemsSource;

        DataTable dt = dataView.ToTable();

        //test
        double val = dt.Rows[1].Field<double>("utez");
        MessageBox.Show(val.ToString());

    }
```

How do i get the current changed data from DataGrid?
I am using WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You state this line "`seznam.ItemsSource = v.tabela.dt.DefaultView;`" in your description - are you doing that in some code behind or viewmodel setup?  If so then you will be breaking the binding to the property "DataSource" that you're declaring in the xaml.  Is that what you intended?

Your bindings to ime and utez are two-way, so any attempt to write to those locations within the datagrid should be catchable by placing a breakpoint against the property in the viewmodel, and you might be able to get a better idea of what's going on, or rather what's not going on.